# Making comments go to right posts

Tags: php, sql, comments

I have a basic and working posting and comment system in PHP, but im wondering how I can make the comments that are being submitted go to the right post where they belong?

For example, how do I tell the database to show the comments for this topic, and not for all the other topics?

I did a couple searches and didn't find anything i was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Do your posts have an id?

Comment: no, i dont think so. Or yes if you count the AI id i have in the database.

Comment: Are they being saved in a database?

Comment: Yes being saved in database and with a id that the database creates.

Comment: Exactly. So each comment should have the id for that post. And then for each post page, just show the comments that have that id.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks. But how do i make the comment php script to create the same id as the post has?

Comment: Are you writing the comment in the same page as the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert in every comment, the 'id' of the post, then for every post, pull show the comments that have the post id. Check out this tutorial for something similar:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

Comment: I kind of understood it now. But i have a Show comment button under the post. How do i make it know witch post im pressing the "view comment" button on?

Comment: That's very broad, it all depends how you are getting the comments. Can you post some code?

Comment: so i just add a button (echo '<a href="comment.php">View Comments</a>) that takes me to this php script http://pastebin.com/qZd675qi

Comment: do href="comment.php?post_id=X . That way you pass the post id and then use $_GET to get the id. Make sure to validate and sanitize the id that is passed to avoid any security problems.

Comment: ok, now everything seems to be working well exept i cant somehow use the $_GET[post_id] in the script where the comment get inserted to the database even thought i've included it with include ('filename.php');. Any ideas?

Comment: sure. comments.php the file where it shows comments and you can type one http://pastebin.com/hSz4j1xR And comment.php that posts the comments http://pastebin.com/DUZgHHPH

Comment: First let me tell you that this scripts are very Unsecured. If you echo $_GET['post_id'] , does it give you the id?

Comment: Yes i know but they are not made to be so secure atleast yet. But no it is not echoing it out, witch is wierd.

Comment: Do you see it in the browser address bar? Does it show comments.php?post_id=x ?

Comment: and your sure you are doing echo $_GET['post_id'] on that page? Just asking cause I've spent hours trying to fix a typo

Comment: but do an echo $_GET['post_id'] and see if it gives u a value